# connection string without server name

Tags: winforms, client-server, connection-string, sql-server-express

I am developing a c# application with sql server express database that should be run in a local network. I want to make a setup for my project by InstallAware.

I want to know how to set connection string for clients while I don't know the server name, in the other hand I want to connect to database only knowing InstanceName.

```
ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=Accounting;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string GetServerName()
    {
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

        DataTable dt = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("InstanceName='myInstanceName'");

        if (dr.Length == 0)
            return null;

        return dr[0]["ServerName"].ToString();
    }
```